# Как сделать конфиги для тестированя?

Tags: asp.net

При тестировании, не подключаются конфиги:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Не удалось найти строку подключения с именем "Entities" в файле конфигурации приложения..
```

Как сделать конфиги для тестирования или как подключить конфиги?

Comment: Указывайте язык программирования - это привлечёт больше внимания к вопросу. | О каком именно тестировании идёт речь: модульное, интеграционное?..

Comment: Интеграционное тестирование. Он будет же свои конфиги подгружать или конфиги приложения, что я тестирую?